# Strange casting problem Derived to Base in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

I have three classes: Base, Derived (inherits from Base), and Stats (which uses a Base).

The program makes a Derived object, which may be deleted and reconstructed several times during the program's execution. It also sets up a Stats object which will only be created once, but needs to call functions on the Base of the Derived object. Because the Derived object may be reconstructed, the Stats object will need a reference to a pointer of Base, since the value of the pointer may change. However, when I construct a new Derived in main, the reference in the Stats class doesn't see the new object.

In the example below, d and m_obj both are null, then when I make a new Derived instance, m_obj still is null. This doesn't make sense to me. What confuses even more, is if I change the line `Derived* d = 0;` to `Base* d = 0;`, it works fine. Any thoughts?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base {
};

class Derived : public Base {
};

typedef Base* const base_ptr;

class Stats {
public:
    Stats(Base * const &obj) : m_obj(obj) {
        cout << "In Stats():" << endl;
        cout << "   m_obj = " << m_obj << endl;
    }

    void f() const {
        cout << "In f:" << endl;
        cout << "   m_obj = " << m_obj << endl;
    }

private:
    base_ptr &m_obj;
};

int main() {
    Derived* d = 0;
    cout << "d = " << d << endl;

    Stats s(d);

    d = new Derived();
    cout << "d (after new) = " << d << endl;

    s.f();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a reference to a temporary `Base *` that points to what `d` was pointing at (NULL in this case). That temporary is destroyed after line that invokes the constructor finishes executing. Congratulations, you've just invoked undefined behavior! After that, anything can happen.

Essentially, this line reads like this if you expand out what's really happening:

```
Stats s(d);
```

really:

```
{
    Base * const tmp = d;
    Stats s(tmp);
}
```

Except, of course, `s` doesn't go away like it would in this example.

When `d` is of type `Base *` then the compiler doesn't have to do any type conversion and so doesn't have to create any temporaries.

Comment: This was the problem. To fix it I templated the Stats constructor which did a C-style cast so that the caller didn't have to worry about any of this.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Stats` gets actually a temporary copy of the value of `d`. This is because `d` is not of the type `Base * const &` (but can be converted to).